# How can add a good hold point to my bicycle

Tags: accessories

[image]

The bicycle now has a black basket on the back so there is only about 5 cm of this steel bracket (it wouldn't help much to include as it doesn't show how space is available) In a previous thread, answerers said I really shouldn't use the seat to lift however lifting from the steel bracket is awkward for me so I would like to have a column to grab above the  bracket as the only real feasible grab point- is there an off-the-shelf solution for this?

I have turn the bicycle around in tight spaces or keep it upright while getting the stand set up. I don't lack any strength to move the bicycle. I lack good hips and other joints and some general flexibility so it is uncomfortable and possibly bodily damaging to bend to move the bicycle-let alone tempting to just grab the seat.

Comment: What thread was it about lifting by the seat? At least lifting by the seat post should be no problem.

Comment: I can't grabbed the column well either- same height as the bracket.

Comment: I lift my bikes by the nose of the saddle all the time.

Comment: Also plenty of workstands hold either the saddle or seat post.  But if you do want a lift point, please post a picture with the basket fitted.  I have an idea or two that depend on the details of the basket

Answer (score 4):

For any heavier bicycle, it is important to lift over (horizontal) center of mass - this is much easier. You need to know approximately where it could be and adjust if you picked wrongly and front or back is going up as you lift. This point must also be low enough so you conveniently get the wheels high enough off the ground.

With the weight of your basket added, I suspect that the center of mass may be at some point of the seat tube. For "as pictured", the pick point is likely somewhere on the top tube.

Both can be grabbed very easily by hand so I do not think you need installing any additional accessory for this.

Comment: If the bike is of the type shown in the photo I'd say that the ideal right hand position for the CM would be where the upper downtube meets the seat tube. With the left hand steadying the stem.

Answer (score 3):

As the weight is towards the back, for manoeuvring in tight spaces it's easiest to lift by the saddle, which isn't a problem (though it's a little high off the ground for picking it right up).  That also helps with lifting to operate the stand as then you only need to lift the back end.  To lift onto the stand you could also lift by the back edge of the rack, or even the basket if it's a sturdy one.

For actually carrying a bike like that (e.g. stairs) I'd squat down a little, grab that lowered toptube with my right hand, then straighten up.  That lifts with your legs not your back (a good plan), and shouldn't be too hard on your joints.  The left hand can be used on the handlebars to adjust the angle and take just a little weight.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to roll the bike where feasible.  Going up/down stairs is about the only time I'd lift a bike.

In your case, I'd hold the bike by the seat tube or seat post, and use the left hand on the handlebars to stop the front wheel flopping.

Bend your knees, and reach over the toptube to grab hold on the far side.  Lift with your legs, not your back.

I'd try and stand on the left of the bike, opposite the dirtier chain area.  This ends up with the saddle's nose under your right arm, or maybe over your right shoulder depending on your height and arm length.  If the latter, you can rest some of the weight of the bike on your right shoulder.

Comment: You’d need a ton of grip strength to hold a 15kg bicycle by the seat tube. Grab the toptube/downtube. First photo I could find: http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1070/5151782995_abdf26ce6e_o.jpg

Comment: @Michael rather than disagree in comments, post your own answer.

Comment: @Michael *You’d need a ton of grip strength to hold a 15kg bicycle by the seat tube.* Huh?!?!  Why would you need more grip strength to hold the seat tube instead of the top tube or down tube?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Your hand would need to generate enough friction to prevent the seatpost from sliding down inside it.

Comment: I can imagine a small child not having 15 kilos of grip strength, but an adult should be fine with that.  In the pictured bike, one could reach to the top-tube/seat tube intersection and hold there or just at the aft end of the top tube.

Comment: @MaplePanda Neither the seat post nor the seat tube are an infinite rod without projections - if they slide at all.  Average male human grip is about 40 kgf, and a human palm has a coefficient of friction of about .6 - easily enough to support 15 kg without sliding.  So no, you don't need a "ton of grip" to grab a 15 kg bike by the seat post and lift it safely without sliding.  You need "only about 2/3 of a merely average human grip".

Comment: Just try walking up or down a single flight of stairs with a 15kg bike held by the seattube only. I think most average adults can’t do biceps curls with a 15kg weight. Holding it by the top- or downtube is really the only feasible way and the way cyclocross and MTB riders do it regularly.

Comment: @Michael [Ummm, check these...](https://www.google.com/search?q=average+human+dumbell+curl+strength)  15 kg dumbbell curls are actually on the light side.  Note the weights used on a lot of those sites you'll see are for actual **workouts** with dumbbells.  You're actually fixated on this to the point of downvoting it why? Most people have more than enough grip that it's not going to slip, and even if they don't they can brace the top of their hand against the saddle clamp or the chainstays to prevent slipping.  The seat post/tube is every bit as good of a handle as the top tube.

Comment: @Michael where do bicep curls come into it? If you try curling a bike you'll get a saddle in the face.  Holding by the seat tube your arm should be hanging down, slightly out to one side which means the tricep will be doing a bit of work.  That said, I can curl 15kg without much trouble, and would prefer to lift by something other that the seat post for reasons of comfort.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I suppose it is only an issue in a world where all gases are ideal, all collisions are elastic, all cows are spherical, and friction is negligible…

Comment: @MaplePanda Wait! Cows aren't spherical?!?!  Well dang, and I thought 2020 and 2021 were bad years and now you go and ruin 2022 right off the bat like that?!???  ;-)

Comment: I had to move the bikes around in my garage, so I did a little bit of testing.  My tourer is hard to lift completely off the ground by the seat tube, because the long reach and aero bars put the centre of gravity too far forwards.  It's just doable if you grip as low as possible.  The hybrid lifts nicely by the seat tube despite a D lock on the forks.  Both are over 20kg with the racks/locks/tools on them at the moment, and can be curled holding by the toptube though I never need to - the rack on my van is too high for that